# can we create a web service using objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, soap

In my iphone application I am calling (by SOAP post method) a web service which is written in .net and hosted on a server, and its all working fine. But my doubt is, can we write a web service in objective c? And host it on a server? so that we should be able to access it from any of the platforms like .net, php and objectiveC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read a fantastic tutorial regarding this question some time ago [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html).

To be honest, it can be quite difficult to really use this in a productive environment. If you want to get all the features and tools Apple gives to you (what seems to be the intention of your question), you'll have to use a Mac in order to run your service afterwards.

In my opionion using PHP for example (if you need a db also backed up by MySQL) is much easier. Almost all hosters support it and you won't have to worry about setting up a bunch of macs and connecting them via solid and stable cables to the internet (and with that: guarantee availability).

Comment: 276/5000
I think this does not answer the question although it is accepted. The question is focused on Web Services SOAP, not on an HTTP server as described in the link. Although SOAP can be executed using http by writing the request xml, it seems to me that the answer is halved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A web service is just some application that can provide a service over the web. As you can create an application in Objective C, it can be a web service the same as made in any other language.

You can make it run on any server where you have an objective C compiler, however, the framework you use may restrict your choices to the server (ie, you can write objective C on windows, but you wouldn't be able to use the NS framework)

Answer (score 0):

Web services are not limited to a programming language, however you do need to find if there is any framework using objective-c can run on specific server. For example, iiS allows you to use Asp.net which could be implemented using C# or VB.Net.

From the clients who will consume web services, they don't have to be a specific type of device. I think that's the point of web services. The messages travel in between is formatted. For example, a SOAP message is using xml, and that would ensure the message travel on HTTP. Therefore no matter you use iPhone or Android or Blackberry, you should have no problem to make web service calls.

So in general, I think you have to see what kind of web services you want to create, and then see if Apple(I assume) can provide you with a good framework to do it. In terms of client side, as long as your web services are using XML or JSON, it should be well supported.

Hope it helps.